# Testing concurrent request to same URL using Zombie.js

Tags: node.js, zombie.js

Is there any ways to simulate about 200 request to the same URL using Zombie.js inorder to check the performance of a node server.

Comment: I think Zombie is pretty slow, so if you want to test the performance of your server, try something specifically meant for that like httperf or apachebench/ab.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to simulate as a complete browser running javascript and supporting websocket. Zombie supports all this. I dont think apachebench supports websocket or runs client side script.

Comment: That's true, although you will probably end up testing the performance of Zombie.js instead of the performance of your server :)